# Formatting the pie chart's tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a pie chart that contains various values. When hovering over a slice of the pie, the value is displayed. I'd like to make the value displayed a percentage. For example, I want 11 to be 11%. Is it possible to add a percent symbol to all values when hovering over the slice? Here's my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysw1kovt/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

**JS**

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work', 11],
      ['Eat', 2],
      ['Commute', 2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep', 7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      tooltip: {
        text: 'value'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tooltip will display the formatted value of the row by default

format the data table column before drawing the chart...

```
var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
  suffix: '%',
  fractionDigits: 0
});
formatNumber.format(data, 1);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    suffix: '%',
    fractionDigits: 0
  });
  formatNumber.format(data, 1);

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    tooltip: {
      text: 'value'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: This works, but it rounds up the decimals. How can I display 2 places after the decimal?

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change the fractionDigits to 2 for that to work

Answer (score 1):

Curious about your use case, but this works. Google visualization allows you to add [custom labels](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole) for each data point.

```js
      google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
      });
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day')
            data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'})
            data.addRows([
              ['Work', 11, '11%'],
              ['Eat', 2, '2%'],
              ['Commute', 2, '2%'],
              ['Watch TV', 2, '2%'],
              ['Sleep', 7, '7%']
            ]);
       
        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          tooltip: {
            text: 'value'
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?fake=.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```